# Modifications to lillypond file

Tags: lilypond

Here is my code:

```
\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
\relative{
  \time 2/4
  c' c _"C.1"|
  c cs |
  c d |
  c ds |
  c e |
  c f |
  c g' |
  c, a' |
  c, as' |
  c, b' |
}
\end{lilypond}
```

It generates this:

[image]

What I need and don't know how to do:

1. Remove the clef and the meter marks
2. Instead of "C.1" put the Russian "Ч.1"
3. Shift the "C.1" text below the first pitch, so it was nicely centered.

Comment: Just for the record: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260577/7047 on the LaTeX-related part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```latex
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
\relative{
  \omit Staff.Clef
  \omit Staff.TimeSignature
  \time 2/4
  c' _"Ч.1" c |
  c cs |
  c d |
  c ds |
  c e |
  c f |
  c g' |
  c, a' |
  c, as' |
  c, b' |
}
```

Just put it into a file named `document.ly` (for example) and run lilypond on it:

`lilypond --pdf document.ly`

(replace `--pdf`with `--png` if you want a PNG as result). This should produce a PDF with the following content:

[image]

Tested with GNU LilyPond 2.18.2 on Ubuntu Vivid (15.04).

Comment: How did you get the Russian character? I tried `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` in Latex, but it doesn't work. Prints an empty space.

Comment: @user4035: I've integrated those information in my answer, so i removed my comments.

Comment: When I compile using your command it works. When I do it from latex, it doesn't. Thank you.